# Swift DateFormatter converting string day/times incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, date

I'm trying to convert time strings that look like the following into Swift Dates:

Sun 11:00a PDT

Sun 7:00p PDT

Mon 11:00a PDT

Mon 7:00p PDT

Tue 11:00a PDT

Tue 7:00p PDT

Wed 10:00a PDT

Wed 7:00p PDT

etc

These represent opening and closing times for various businesses.

While the Date object conversion does succeed (meaning the returned optional is not *nil*,) the times are incorrect. Here is my code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let shortDays = ["Sun-","Mon-","Tue-","Wed-","Thu-","Fri-","Sat-"]
            
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E HH:mmaaaaa zzz"
var daysCounter = 0
            
for hours in hoursArray {
    let dayHours = shortDays[daysCounter]+hours
                
    //split hours
    let splitHours = dayHours.split(separator: "-")
    //print(String(splitHours[0]+" "+splitHours[1]+" "+timezone))
    //print(String(splitHours[0]+" "+splitHours[2]+" "+timezone))
    //create an opening time date optional
                
    let openingOpt = dateFormatter.date(from: String(splitHours[0]+" "+splitHours[1]+" "+timezone))
                
    //create a closing time date optional
    let closingOpt = dateFormatter.date(from: String(splitHours[0]+" "+splitHours[2]+" "+timezone))
                
    //unwrap those optionals
    guard let opening = openingOpt else{
    //deal with "closed"
        print("Something happened with unwrapping opening time optional: \(String(describing: openingOpt))")
        return
    }
                
    guard let closing = closingOpt else{
                    //deal with "closed"
        print("Something happened with unwrapping closing time optional: \(String(describing: closingOpt))")
        return
    }
                
    self.fullHours.append(opening)
    self.fullHours.append(closing)
    daysCounter += 1
}
```

```
for hours in fullHours{
    print(hours)
}
```

However, when I print the converted dates using the for loop above, I get incorrect results. Some of the results are fine; for example, the closing times of 7pm seem to convert properly. To the left are the printed Date objects, to the right are the original inputs in parenthesis:

2000-01-02 07:00:00 +0000 (Sun 11:00a PDT)

2000-01-02 19:00:00 +0000 (Sun 7:00p PDT)

2000-01-03 07:00:00 +0000 (Mon 11:00a PDT)

2000-01-03 19:00:00 +0000 (Mon 7:00p PDT)

2000-01-04 07:00:00 +0000 (Tue 11:00a PDT)

2000-01-04 19:00:00 +0000 (Tue 7:00p PDT)

2000-01-05 07:00:00 +0000 (Wed 10:00a PDT)

2000-01-05 19:00:00 +0000 (Wed 7:00p PDT)

2000-01-06 07:00:00 +0000 (Thu 11:00a PDT)

2000-01-06 19:00:00 +0000 (Thu 7:00p PDT)

2000-01-07 07:00:00 +0000 (Fri 11:00a PDT)

2000-01-07 19:00:00 +0000 (Fri 7:00p PDT)

12000-01-01 07:00:00 +0000 (Sat 11:00a PDT)

2000-01-01 19:00:00 +0000 (Sat 7:00p PDT)

In particular, why is Saturday being converted to the year 12000? Why does Wednesday at 10am still show at 7am UTC? I'm confused and lost, and could not find a similar question via search. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Note: I am using Xcode 13.0 Beta 5, developing for iOS 15 beta 5.

Edit: here is the source for the date-time formatting: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Edit2: Also, I discovered that any time appended with "a" converts to 7am, and any time appended with "p" converts to 7pm. So... ??

Comment: Where does the date-time format of 'E HH:mmaaaaa zzz' come from?

Comment: This Unicode Standard: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Are you sure you read that carefully enough? It clearly tells you the difference between `HH` and `h`. And in this case, you clearly should use the latter.

Comment: You are 100% right! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that my format was off. It should have been h:mm, not HH:mm. Thanks to Sweeper for the detail-oriented answer!